# Error while compiling: DASD.cs(109,195): error CS1503

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Code:

```
private void Executing(PlayerSession Player, string response, int code)
{
    switch (code)
    {
        case 0:
            Debug.LogError("Api does not responded to a request");
            break;
        case 200:
            Dictionary<string, object> Response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(response, new KeyValuesConverter());
            if (Response != null)
            {
                switch (Convert.ToInt32(Response["code"]))
                {
                    case 100:
                        int i = 0;
                        List<object> data = Response["data"] as List<object>;
                        foreach (object pair in data) 
                        {
                            if (i >= 14)
                            {
                                hurt.SendChatMessage(Player, $"Вы не можете получить больше 14 предметов за раз.");
                                return;
                            }

                            Dictionary<string, object> iteminfo = pair as Dictionary<string, object>;

                            if(iteminfo.ContainsKey("command"))
                            {
                                string command = iteminfo["command"].ToString().Replace('\n', '|').ToLower().Trim('\"').Replace("%steamid%", Player.SteamId.m_SteamID.ToString()).Replace("%username%", Player.Name);
                                String[] CommandArray = command.Split('|');
                                foreach (var substring in CommandArray)
                                {
                                    ConsoleManager.Instance.ExecuteCommand(substring);
                                }
                                hurt.SendChatMessage(Player, $"Получен товар из магазина: <color=lime>\"{iteminfo["name"]}\"</color>.");
                                SendGived(new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "gived", "true" }, { "id", $"{iteminfo["id"]}" } }, Player);
                                return;
                            }

                            int ItemID = Convert.ToInt32(iteminfo["item_id"]);
                            int Amount = Convert.ToInt32(iteminfo["amount"]);
                            ItemInstance Item = new ItemInstance(GlobalItemManager.Instance.GetItem(ItemID), Amount);

                            if (Player.WorldPlayerEntity.GetComponent<Inventory>().GiveItemServer(Item))
                            {
                                Singleton<AlertManager>.Instance.GenericTextNotificationServer($"Получен товар из магазина: \"{iteminfo["name"]}\" в количестве {Amount}", session.Player);
                            } else {
                                hurt.SendChatMessage(Player, $"В инвентаре недостаточно места для получения <color=lime>\"{iteminfo["name"]}\"</color>");
                                return;
                            }
                            i++;  
                        }
                        break;
                    case 104:
                        hurt.SendChatMessage(Player, $"Ваша корзина пуста!");
                        break;
                }
            }
            else
                Debug.LogWarning(response);
            break;
        case 404:
            Debug.LogError("Response code: 404, please check your configurations");
            break;
    }
}
```

Error the line

```
Singleton<AlertManager>.Instance.GenericTextNotificationServer($"Получен товар из магазина: \"{iteminfo["name"]}\" в количестве {Amount}", Player);
```

Error:

> Error while compiling: DASD.cs(109,195): error CS1503: Argument '#2' cannot convert 'PlayerSession' expression to type 'uLink.NetworkPlayer'

Comment: Doesn't the error _tell_ you what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Method `Singleton<AlertManager>.Instance.GenericTextNotificationServ‌​er()` accepts in its second parameter a variable of type `uLink.NetworkPlayer`, you pass of type `PlayerSession`.

So apparently you need to pass `session`, not `session.Player`.

Comment: error CS0103: The name `session' does not exist in the current context

Comment: @ПавелПрусс: you have a line of code `Singleton<AlertManager>.Instance.GenericTextNotificationServer($"Получен товар из магазина: \"{iteminfo["name"]}\" в количестве {Amount}", session.Player);` where you clearly have `session`.

Comment: My mistake, I'm sorry. 
When there is a string session.Player, there is an error "error CS0103: The name` session 'does not exist in the current context ".  When it's just a Player string, it goes out
"Argument` # 2 'can not convert `PlayerSession' expression to type` uLink.NetworkPlayer '"

Comment: I changed line,but now another mistake "Singleton<AlertManager>.Instance.GenericTextNotificationServer(Player, $"Получен товар из магазина: \"{iteminfo["name"]}\" в количестве {Amount}."); ".                                                                                   
    Error: "error CS1503: Argument `#1' cannot convert `PlayerSession' expression to type `string'".

Comment: @ПавелПрусс: I'm sorry, those are compiler errors, I can't troubleshoot them from the remote. I would suggest to write something simpler to get more familiar with C#